# o-auth login with wykop.pl

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-5

Now I wish to build a login function with Wykop.pl API. 
Can anybody help me to setup the thing?

As of now, I don't even have clue how to fill the 
    'scope'         => array()
not to mention which privileges I should enable when connecting my app to wykop.pl

```
'Wykop' => array(
'client_id'     => '423423',
'client_secret' => '0XMRI423423BfDFG',
'redirect_url'  => 'http://www.appname.pl/dashboard',
'scope'         => array('login', 'klucz_polaczenia','profile'),
```

),

This is a SDK for the site https://github.com/p1c2u/wykop-sdk
Unfortunately, as for now I am unable to translate the code into sth useful to me.

For the purpose of o-auth login, should scope include 'login' and 'klucz_polaczenia' ?

---

After the function is done, it would be a good idea to add the example to 
this project repository of examples:

https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib/tree/master/examples

### Edit:

Wykop is not using o-auth... so the package I was trying to use is of no value.
Any help appreciated.

### Edit 2:

The clostest I got to my goal is using this repo:

```
https://github.com/matiit/wkop
```

Comment: No one will work for you. Read API docs, and write a code. If you will have a problem with code, come back. But if you want to find an employee, find him on Careers.

Comment: I have read the API, made several attempts. I cannot figure it out - I am not a professional programmer. Anyway, try to be more problem-oriented in comments here, as SO is a place to ask for and provide free help. Thx.

Comment: SO is place, where people help to figure problems with YOUR code. Where are your code snippets? Where are questions connected to a specific problem? Now your thread doesn't fit any of SO standards. It seems like looking for a slave, who will do everything for me, and for free.

Pro tip: create a new thread, ask more specific questions, and never forget to paste your code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

I did this recently. I'm using following workflow:

- Display the login form to the user, with redirect set to callback.
- Check the signature of callback, if correct then proceed.
- Check, if I can login on Wykop.pl with received token, if so, then proceed.
- Check, if user exists in my database, if so, I login him, if not, I create and login him.

Whole process of connecting with Wykop.pl API is available here: http://www.wykop.pl/dla-programistow/dokumentacja/#info6_7_5

Comment: Thank you! With kind help from 3 guys and now you I am now close to solution. If I fail to produce results in 3 attempts, I will come back and ask more educated question.

Comment: Someone suggested a good starting point here: 
https://github.com/frizikk/sztafeta-wykop/blob/master/wykopAPI.php and Wykop.pl staff suggested, that all info is http://www.wykop.pl/dla-programistow/dokumentacja/#info10_1